# Can't Import Module

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

First of all, this is very likely not a path issue.

I have a pydev project in eclipse. Here is the directory structure:

```
Genetic-Framework
  | Genetic-Framework
    | Genetic
      | __init__.py
      | GA.py
      | crossover.py
      | fitness.py
      | individual.py
      | mutation.py
      | population.py
      | selection.py
      | settings.py
      | visualization.py
```

In `GA.py`, I have the following line:

```
from Genetic import settings, selection, visualization as vis
```

And yes, `Genetic` is in `sys.path`. However, I get the following error:

```
  File "/.../Genetic-Framework/Genetic-Framework/Genetic/GA.py", line 17, in <module>
    from Genetic import settings, selection, visualization as vis
ImportError: cannot import name settings
```

However, when I remove `settings` from that line, everything else imports just fine.

Interestingly, among the first lines of `settings.py` is this:

```
from Genetic import fitness, selection, mutation, crossover, population, GA
```

And when I remove `GA` from that line, everything seems to import just fine.

Why am I getting this error? Is this some issue with circular imports? How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to have an `__init__.py` file for this to work at all.  Is there a file named `Genetic.py` somewhere on your path?  It's possible that it's not importing what you think it's importing.

Comment: There /is/ an `__init__.py` I excluded it from the dir list in my post because I thought it was irrelevant. Post edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's an issue with circular imports.

### The problem

The problem is that when your `GA.py` is run, it first tries to import `settings`. This means that `settings.py` starts getting run, and it immediately tries to import `GA`.

However, `GA` is already in the process of loading, so `GA.py` doesn't get run a second time - instead, `settings` just loads the `GA` that is already in memory (which is currently mostly empty, because it's still executing its imports).

Thus, things in `settings` that try to use things out of `GA` fail, because the things they're looking for in `GA` haven't been defined yet (because processing of `GA.py` hasn't gotten past the imports yet).

This makes the evaluation of `settings.py` raise an exception, which manifests as a failure to be imported (because an exception raised during import makes the import fail).

### The solution

#### a) Avoid the situation in the first place.

In general, you should try to avoid circular imports in the first place. They often mean that you have really odd dependency structure that will be hard to debug later.

One way to do this is to try to find things that are needed in both modules and break them out into a separate third module that can be shared between the other two - so instead of using A.x in B, and B.y in A, you instead use C.x and C.y in both A and B.

#### b) Don't actually try to use things from circular imports until everything's loaded.

Another thing you can do is to defer usage of something from another module until after all of the imports have finished. In other words, don't try to reference an imported module's contents from top-level code, but instead place it in a class initializer or a function that you can call later on, once all of the imports have finished.

For example, instead of this...

```
import Foo

class Baz:
    top_level_variable = Foo.bar
```

you can do this:

```
import Foo

class Baz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_variable = Foo.bar
```

Obviously, instance properties are slightly different from class properties, but the idea is to defer actually having to look things up from other modules until after all of the modules finish executing and thus have their contents available. Also note that `from Foo import bar` would fail here because that tries to access the contents of `Foo` at the time of the import, which is what needs to be avoided.

Comment: You were doing well until you got to option b, which doesn't work at all. Python doesn't care when you refer to the contents of a module: the very fact of importing it means it must be parsed, which leads to the circular dependency. Moving the *import* into the `__init__` function is, however, a potential solution.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: It's true that the module must be parsed, but that doesn't mean all objects have to be fully available.  What you say is true for `from ... import ...`, but when you use a bare `import foo`, as long as the imported module can be properly parsed, you can get away with a circular import as long as you don't attempt to access variables from it until after the module is loaded, it will be okay.  The crucial thing is that in the second example in B above, the code accessing `Foo.bar` is not executed at module-import time.

Comment: @BrenBarn nailed it. The issue occurs not when the import happens, but when the importing module attempts to *access* something within the imported module. If you can avoid such accesses (which necessarily includes avoiding `from ... import ...` format imports), then it will work.

Comment: Is there a way that I could import everything (say with a call to import in `__init__.py`) so that I can remove import statements from the individual modules themselves?