# Circular import in marshmallow

Tags: python, python-import, importerror, marshmallow

I have two objects that are related to one another.  I'd like to be able to access one object through the other by going through the related attribute.

E.g. `A.b_relationship.obj.some_property`

How can I do this without creating a circular import?

```
# lib.py
class Relationship(object):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj


# a.py
class A(object):
    b_relationship = Relationship(B)

# b.py
class B(object):
    a_relationship = Relationship(A)
```

---

For clarity, I've added this additional example.  Obviously SQLAlchemy has solved this issue with the `backref` attribute.  I'm not sure how feasible it would be for me to implement this sort of thing into marshmallow without breaking the way it works.  Perhaps I need to change my mindset?

```
from marshmallow import Schema
from marshmallow.fields import String

from project.database import db


class PersonModel(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String)


class PetModel(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    owner = db.relationship('PersonModel', backref='pets')


class PersonSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String(init_arg='some value')
    pets = fields.Relationship(related_schema=PetSchema)


class PetSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.String()
    owner = fields.Relationship(related_schema=PersonSchema)
```

Comment: Make an `__init__` and import `A` and `B` there. Then you can avoid circular imports in a.py and b.py. [This might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13444900/198633)

Comment: You say you have two objects related to one another, but you're setting the relationships at class level. While classes are indeed objects, this doesn't seem like a useful link to create. Do you want an instance of A to be linked to an instance of B and vice versa, or do you want the classes to be linked? A class-level link is pretty useless. Also, how are instances of these classes created? Do they come into existence together, or are they created independently?

Comment: @user2357112 The classes themselves shouldn't be linked together.  They don't care about one another.  Its the `_relationship` attributes that need to be linked.  I key off those fields later on and use the linked obj to do some calculation.

Comment: @user2357112 Basically, I want to be able to do `A.rel` to get `B` and `B.rel` to get `A`.

Comment: then you need to make the `relationship` attribute an `instance` attribute, not a `class` attribute as they are now. BTW, drop the prefix (`a_` and `b_`)

Comment: uhm... I replied to your reply above, but now your latest comment is even more confusing. Do you want to relate `classes` or `objects`?

Comment: What's the class `Relationship` meant to do in practice? I have the feeling it's not necessary. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @François All I want to do is to enable some configuration such that I can view attributes of one object on another.  So if I'm working with instance `B` and I want to know the value of some field on object `A`.  I can get to `A` by going through a special attribute on `B`.

Comment: @Pynchia I'm using `marshmallow`.  You define fields on a schema object.  Those fields are themselves objects.  Some objects represent relationships in the database.  Since the sqlalchemy models are linked, I'd like the schemas to be linked in a similar manner so I can perform some useful cross schema validation.

Comment: @ColtonAllen could you provide a concrete example of what might A and B might be? and of a property?

Comment: @François I've added an example.  A and B are the schema objects.

Comment: Ah, it's for an ORM ! Never heard of `marshmallow` but I've replied anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From here:
http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nesting.html#two-way-nesting

See how a string is used for the class; AuthorSchema refers to 'BookSchema':

```
class AuthorSchema(Schema):
    # Make sure to use the 'only' or 'exclude' params
    # to avoid infinite recursion
    books = fields.Nested('BookSchema', many=True, exclude=('author', ))
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'books')

class BookSchema(Schema):
    author = fields.Nested(AuthorSchema, only=('id', 'name'))
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'author')
```

---

I assume in your case, you want to do the same thing with `many=False`. I've never used marshmallow but in Django, it's similar, we use class path like "my_app.MyClass" instead of `MyClass` to avoid circular import.

Comment: Thanks bud!  I didn't realize marshmallow had this feature already.  That's what I get for assuming.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a `RelationshipManager` (aka a registry), which all classes that can be part of a relationship must be registered with.

The `Relationship` initialiser could take then the *name* of the class it's related to, rather than the actual class object.

Finally, the relationship class itself can lazy-load the real class it's related to from the name it's given at initialisation (via the manager).